# RX UDPClient that listeners for messages from devices from a list of ports and subscribes to data to post to Azure Event Hub

Tags: c#, azure, udp, system.reactive

I have some code which rolls through a list of ports and sets up a stream containing the UDP Buffer contents which can be subscribed to.

I'm pretty new to RX and this was built with some help in response to another stackoverflow question.

This code seemed to be OK in early tests and handled all the packets we could send it but now it's in soak test the subscription seems to fail after a while and it stops sending events to the event hub.

I'm particularly worried that I have an exception somewhere in the subscription code which causes me to lose the information but isn't caught.

Here is the code, any comments or suggestions for simplification or improvement would be greatly appreciated:

```
var receiveStream =
    _deviceTypeProvider.GetDeviceTypes().ToObservable().Trace("GetDeviceTypes")
        .SelectMany(devicePortMapping => Observable
            .Using(() => UdpListener(devicePortMapping),
                client =>
                    Observable
                        .FromAsync(client.ReceiveAsync)
                        .Repeat()).Trace("UdpListener"),
            (devicePortMapping, stream) =>
            {
                Log
                    .ForContext("Raw", stream.Buffer.ToPrintByteArray())
                    .Verbose("Received Incoming {DeviceType} Message from {Device} on Port {Port}",
                        devicePortMapping.DeviceType, stream.RemoteEndPoint.Address, devicePortMapping.Port);
                try
                {
                    var timeZoneOffset =
                        _deviceTimeZoneOffsetProvider.GetDeviceTimeZoneOffset(devicePortMapping.Port);

                    var tenant = _deviceTenantProvider.GetDeviceTenant(devicePortMapping.Port);

                    if (tenant == null || timeZoneOffset == null)
                    {
                        Log
                            .Error(
                                "Tenant or TimeOffset Missing for Port: {Port}, cannot continue processing this message",
                                devicePortMapping.Port);

                        return null;
                    }

                    var message =
                        new DeviceMessage(new Device(stream.RemoteEndPoint.Address.ToIPAddressNum(),
                            stream.RemoteEndPoint.Port, devicePortMapping.DeviceType, tenant.TenantId,
                            timeZoneOffset.Offset))
                        {
                            MessageUid = Guid.NewGuid(),
                            Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow,
                            Raw = stream.Buffer,
                        };

                    message.Information("Received Incoming Message");

                    return message;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Log.Error(ex, "Exception whilst receiving incoming message");
                    throw;
                }
            }).Trace("SelectMany").Select(Task.FromResult).Trace("Select");

if (_settings.TestModeEnabled)
{
    Log
        .Warning("Test Mode is Enabled");

    receiveStream = receiveStream
        .Select(async message =>
            await _testModeProvider.InjectTestModeAsync(await message)).Trace("TestMode");
}

_listener = receiveStream.Subscribe(async messageTask =>
{
    var message = await messageTask;

    if (message == null)
    {
        Log
            .Warning("Message is null, returning");

        return;
    }

    Log
        .ForContext("Raw", message.Raw.ToPrintByteArray(), true)
        .ForContext("Device", message.Device, true)
        .Verbose("Publishing Message {MessageUid} from {@Device}", message.MessageUid, message.Device);

    await _messagePublisher.Publish(message).ConfigureAwait(false);
}, error => { Log.Error(error, "Exception whilst publishing message"); });
```

Here is the InjectTestMode method:

```
 public async Task<DeviceMessage> InjectTestModeAsync(DeviceMessage deviceMessage)
    {
        try
        {
            var imei = GetImei(deviceMessage.Raw);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(imei))
            {
                Log
                    .ForContext("DeviceMessage",deviceMessage,true)
                    .Error("Error while getting IMEI value from message raw data in Test Mode");

                return null;
            }

            //var dummyIpAddress = DummyIPfromIMEI(imei).ToIPAddressNum();
            var mapping = await _mappingService.GetIPMappingAsync(deviceMessage.Device.IPAddress);

            if (mapping == null)
            {
                Log
                 .ForContext("DeviceMessage", deviceMessage, true)
                 .Warning("Test Mode updated IP Address mapping with IPAddress: {IPAddress} for IMEI: {IMEI}", deviceMessage.Device.IPAddress.ToIPAddressString(), imei);

                await _mappingService.UpdateIPMappingAsync(deviceMessage.Device.IPAddress, imei);
            }


            // deviceMessage.Device.IPAddress = dummyIpAddress;

            return deviceMessage;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log
                .ForContext("DeviceMessage",deviceMessage,true)
                .Error("Exception raised whilst injecting Test Mode", ex);

            return null;
        }
    }
```

Here is the UdpListener method:

```
private UdpClient UdpListener(DeviceTypeMap deviceTypeMap)
    {
        Log.Information("Listening for Device Type: {DeviceType} messages on Port: {Port}", deviceTypeMap.DeviceType,
            deviceTypeMap.Port);

        var udpClient = new UdpClient();

        var serverEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, deviceTypeMap.Port);

        udpClient.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
        udpClient.Client.Bind(serverEndpoint);

        return udpClient;
    }
```

**[Update] - 16/11/2015**

So I've done some research and it would seem I have more than one code smell in this so I've updated the code and it's now running but I thought I'd share the intent of this code and well as the revised code to see if someone can suggest a more elegant solution.

**The Intent**

Listen to several UDP Ports and send the traffic to Azure Event Hubs along with some meta based on the port it was received on.

This meta would depend on whether the system was in a 'Test Mode' or not.

**The Implementation**

For each Port and Device Type create a UDPListener and Observable Collection from the ReceiveAsync event, combine these Observable Collections into a single collection which could then be subscribed from component which would publish the data to EventHubs.

**The Problems**

The InjectMode was async, and this could return a null if there was a problem, this seemed to be killing the sequence. I think that this probably should have been some sort of Observable Extension Method which allow as to modify or remove the device message from the sequence but I couldn't figure this out.

Originally the publish to EventHub was in the subscription until I read that that you shouldn't use async inside a subscription as it generates a `async void` which is bad. All the research seemed to point to pushing this into a SelectMany which did'nt make any sense since this was the destination of the observed sequence not part of the process but I went with this. The subscription in effect became redundant.

I not sure that all of the try catch blocks were required but I was convinced that I had a problem which was disrupted the sequence. As noted by Enigmativity I made these all Exception catches and logged then and re-throw, nothing ever appeared from these log entries.

`Retry().Do()` doesn't feel right, I could get `SelectMany()` as suggested in many other posts to work so I had no choice.

Here's the code which is running now :

```
public void Start()
{
    Log.Information("InboundUdpListener is starting");

    var receiveStream =
        _deviceTypeProvider.GetDeviceTypes().ToObservable().Trace("GetDeviceTypes")
            .SelectMany(devicePortMapping => Observable
                .Using(() => UdpListener(devicePortMapping),
                    client =>
                        Observable
                            .FromAsync(client.ReceiveAsync)
                            .Repeat()).Trace("UdpListener"),
                (devicePortMapping, stream) =>
                {
                    Log
                        .ForContext("Raw", stream.Buffer.ToPrintByteArray())
                        .Verbose("Received Incoming {DeviceType} Message from {Device} on Port {Port}",
                            devicePortMapping.DeviceType, stream.RemoteEndPoint.Address, devicePortMapping.Port);
                    try
                    {
                        var timeZoneOffset =
                            _deviceTimeZoneOffsetProvider.GetDeviceTimeZoneOffset(devicePortMapping.Port);

                        var tenant = _deviceTenantProvider.GetDeviceTenant(devicePortMapping.Port);

                        if (tenant == null || timeZoneOffset == null)
                        {
                            Log
                                .Error(
                                    "Tenant or TimeOffset Missing for Port: {Port}, cannot continue processing this message",
                                    devicePortMapping.Port);

                            return null;
                        }

                        var message =
                            new DeviceMessage(new Device(stream.RemoteEndPoint.Address.ToIPAddressNum(),
                                stream.RemoteEndPoint.Port, devicePortMapping.DeviceType, tenant.TenantId,
                                timeZoneOffset.Offset))
                            {
                                MessageUid = Guid.NewGuid(),
                                Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow,
                                Raw = stream.Buffer,
                            };

                        message.Information("Received Incoming Message");

                        return message;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Log.Error(ex, "Exception whilst receiving incoming message");
                        throw;
                    }
                }).Trace("SelectMany");

    receiveStream = receiveStream.Retry().Do(async message =>
    {
        try
        {
            if (_testModeEnabled && message != null)
            {
                message = await _testModeProvider.InjectTestModeAsync(message);
            }

            if (message != null)
            {
                await _messagePublisher.Publish(message);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error(ex, "Exception whilst publishing incoming message");
            throw;
        }
    }).Trace("Publish");

    _listener = receiveStream.Retry().Subscribe(OnMessageReceive, OnError, OnComplete);

    Log.Information("InboundUdpListener is started");
}
```

Can anyone see any issues with this code or suggest any improvements. I really would appreciate some help with this.

**[Update Following Lee's Comment]**

I totally agree that it was a mess and to show I'm willing to learn take on board people's help this is my next attempt

```
    public void Start()
    {
        _listener = _deviceTypeProvider.GetDeviceTypes().ToObservable()
            .SelectMany(CreateUdpListener, CreateMessage)
            .SelectMany(InjectTestMode)
            .SelectMany(PublishMessage)
            .Retry()
            .Subscribe(OnMessageReceive, OnError, OnComplete);
    }

    private IObservable<UdpReceiveResult> CreateUdpListener(DeviceTypeMap deviceType)
    {
        return Observable.Using(() => UdpListener(deviceType),
            client => Observable.FromAsync(client.ReceiveAsync).Repeat());
    }

    private DeviceMessage CreateMessage(DeviceTypeMap deviceTypeMap, UdpReceiveResult receiveResult)
    {
        var timeZoneOffset =
            _deviceTimeZoneOffsetProvider.GetDeviceTimeZoneOffset(deviceTypeMap.Port);

        var tenant = _deviceTenantProvider.GetDeviceTenant(deviceTypeMap.Port);

        if (tenant == null || timeZoneOffset == null)
        {
            Log
                .Error(
                    "Tenant or TimeOffset Missing for Port: {Port}, cannot continue processing this message",
                    deviceTypeMap.Port);

            return null;
        }

        var message =
            new DeviceMessage(new Device(receiveResult.RemoteEndPoint.Address.ToIPAddressNum(),
                receiveResult.RemoteEndPoint.Port, deviceTypeMap.DeviceType, tenant.TenantId,
                timeZoneOffset.Offset))
            {
                MessageUid = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow,
                Raw = receiveResult.Buffer,
            };

        message.Information("Received Incoming Message");

        return message;
    }

    private async Task<DeviceMessage> InjectTestMode(DeviceMessage message)
    {
        if (_testModeEnabled && message != null)
        {
            message = await _testModeProvider.InjectTestModeAsync(message);
        }

        return message;
    }
    private async Task<DeviceMessage> PublishMessage(DeviceMessage message)
    {
        await _messagePublisher.Publish(message);

        return message;
    }

    private void OnComplete()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private void OnError(Exception ex)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private void OnMessageReceive(object o)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

**[Final Update]**

This is what we finally ended up with; an IObservable>

```
var listeners = Observable.Defer(() => _deviceTypeProvider.GetDeviceTypes()
                .ToObservable()
                .Select(UdpListener)
                .SelectMany(listener =>
                {
                    return Observable.Defer(() => Observable
                        .FromAsync(listener.UdpClient.ReceiveAsync)
                        .Where(x => x.Buffer.Length > 0)
                        .Repeat()
                        .Select(result => CreateMessage(listener.DeviceType, result))
                        .SelectMany(InjectTestMode)
                        .OfType<DeviceMessage>()
                        .Do(async message => await PublishMessage(message)))
                        .Retry();
                })).Retry();

            _listener = listeners.Subscribe(OnMessageReceive, OnError, OnComplete);
```

Comment: Please don't do `catch (Exception ex)`. It's a terrible practice to get into. It's as bad for writing good programs as `goto`. You should only ever catch specific exceptions that you know you can meaningfully handle.

Comment: Yep, it was done quickly when we knew we had this issue, I'm not even sure it's valid practice to put try catch inside the method groups, I thought that was what the OnError was. It's sign of my desperation to try to find the issue.

Comment: If you could provide code that I could copy-paste and run then I could try debugging.

Comment: The first thing I would say is that query is just too big. Break it down into meaningful parts, or you will always struggle with it. Async/Concurrent programming is already hard enough, dont make it worse by having queries that are over 10lines long.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. If you really want help, then you should rip out all of the noise in that code (Log statements) and provide a working sample piece of code that someone can run themselves (so no magic `Trace` operators )

Comment: I'm currently working on cutting up the code like Lee mentioned, it's grown out of control. What I just don't get is why the publish to EventHub can't be in the subscribe, I'm missing something, maybe I don't understand the composition side of RX.

Comment: I am finding that FromAsync immediately followed by repeat is losing packets if they come in too quick. A new packet can come in on the receiveasync before Repeat resubscribed

Answer (score 0):

So I can post some code and be constructive, this is what I think the query in  your `Start` method should look like:

```
_listener = _deviceTypeProvider.GetDeviceTypes().ToObservable()
        .SelectMany(CreateUdpListener, CreateMessage)
        .Retry()
        .Subscribe(OnMessageReceive, OnError, OnComplete);
```

Now the poor guy to come along and support this code has a chance of understanding it. :-)

Comment: I've implemented your feedback and updated the question with the WIP :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the fact that RX sequences do terminate on exceptions. You need to use `Observable.Catch` if you want to continue sequence when exception occur.

See this http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/11_AdvancedErrorHandling.html